# No such file or directory

Tags: python

I can't run my python file due to error saying

```
File "Application.py", line 32, in __init__
self.json_file = open("Models\model_new.json", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Models\\model_new.json'
```

This is my program code

```
class Application:

def __init__(self):

    self.hs = Hunspell('en_US')
    self.vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.current_image = None
    self.current_image2 = None
    self.json_file = open("Models\model_new.json", "r")
    self.model_json = self.json_file.read()
    self.json_file.close()

    self.loaded_model = model_from_json(self.model_json)
    self.loaded_model.load_weights("Models\model_new.h5")
```

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and this is my
[path folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdRmA.png)

Comment: It makes no sense to me, that this question got closed for debugging details. What do you miss? desired behaviour -> opening a file without getting a FileNotFoundError; a specific problem or error -> FileNotFoundError with stacktrace in question-text; shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem -> not really practical I'd say, as the problem is obvious as is and can't be reproduced with just code.

Comment: people that don't know their CWD... ALWAYS have this kind of problem. they show up EVERY day. and ALL the existing answers don't help, because these people don't find them. it's an unsolvable problem because they're beginners on a platform for professionals. what's missing, you ask? a proper MRE, i.e. stripping out everything, and leaving an `assert os.path.exists("Models/model_new.json"), os.getcwd()` ... supposing that the backslash/forward-slash issue isn't actually the issue (python is lenient, interpreting `\m` as literally a backslash and an m, not an invalid escape sequence)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you're running your script in the directory you intend to. You can check this by running `os.getcwd()` or `Path.cwd()` to see where the interpreter currently is.

Secondly, since you're on Ubuntu, you're going to have to change the backslash to a forwardslash, so that your path will be:

```py
open("Models/model_new.json")
```

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks. @vtasca

Comment: this is the first answer that mentions how relative paths are resolved (relative to CWD), and that this is a common issue with beginners.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, your directories are separated by a forward slash. So your path would be: `Models/model_new.json`.

To make your python-scripts work on different operating systems, you can use the os-module:

```
import os

path = os.path.join("Models", "model_new.json")
self.json_file = open(path, "r")
```

If you're interested, where the second slash comes from: This happens, because `\` is used as a special character in strings to represent e.g. newline `\n` or a tab `\t` among others. I don't think, that there is one for `\m`, so python still sees it as just a backslash, but to play it save python does escape the backslash using another one `\\`. This is then the safe representation of a backslash in a string.

You can view this, when printing the repr of your string:

```
print(repr("Models\model_new.json"))
>>> 'Models\\model_new.json'
```